# jaxb2 problem with multiple context paths

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, marshalling

I have a problem related to contexts path in the Jaxb2 marshaller , if I set multiple context paths , the last one will override the others like this :

```
 <bean id="testJaxb2Marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="contextPath" value="com.test.foo.bar.cancel.docin:com.test.foo.bar.acept.docin"/>
</bean>
```

In this case , com.test.foo.bar.acept.docin overrides com.test.foo.bar.cancel.docin

How can I do to set multiple paths in the context path ?

Answer (score 0):

Add Qualifier for each bean in the class as @Qualifier("testJaxb2Marshaller") for class1, @Qualifier("test2Jaxb2Marshaller") for classs2 etc and give that name in the context file.